# Using swift, Is it possible to open a webview in the background to get data from a website once user login info is given?

Tags: ios, swift, api, swift3, uiwebview

I am trying to make a mobile application for an online gradebook called netclassroom. I was not able to use the API that they offer, so I was wondering if it would be possible to open a webview on the side and get data once user credentials are inputted. Would that be considered inefficient? Or is scraping html not the best way to get data compared to using an API?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a Webview to consume a service API sounds like a very bad choice, prone to trigger other problems down the road (error handling might be one). You should rather try to use the API and get SO when in trouble?

Comment: It's possible though, right? The only reason I am not using an API is because I am not associated with their organization, apparently.. so they wont let me.

Comment: If I may suggest, go with the API because it would be cheaper than to go around.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can make a web request (POST/GET) to the same URL instead and read the response as XML